# Drupal6: User Access to Deny Login

Tags: drupal, authentication, logout

I want a permission that will prevent people from logging in. (So, all users of role X could be temporarily blocked, while keeping their profile pages available.)

Excerpt of the login process from Pro Drupal Development 2nd Edition:

1. POST from login form
2. User is blocked?
3. User is denied by access control?

I want to stop users at step three of the process. I have a module:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_perm().
 */
function odp_perm() {
  return array('log in');
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_user
 * lock out without the 'log in' permission
 */
function odp_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
    if ($op == 'login' && ! user_access('log in')) {
      drupal_set_message("You do not have access to log in.", "error");
      drupal_goto('logout'); //doesn't work
      drupal_goto('content/party-tonight'); //also doesn't work
    }
}
```

Perhaps I'm using drupal_goto wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a Drupal instance to test this on ATM, but I think you want this:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_user
 * lock out without the 'log in' permission
 */
function odp_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
    if ($op == 'login' && ! user_access('log in')) {
        global $user;
        $user = drupal_anonymous_user();
        drupal_set_message("You don't have permission to log in");

    }
}
```

That deletes their user info and replaces it with the anonymous user instead.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this accomplishes what you're trying to do.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_user
 * lock out without the 'log in' permission
 */
function odp_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
    if ($op == 'login' && ! user_access('log in')) {
        drupal_set_message("You don't have permission to log in");

        //prevent login
        header("Location: http://www.example.com/?q=logout");
        // header("Location: http://www.example.com/logout"); if using clean URLs
    }
}
```

This logs the user out and displays a message.  If I remember right, hook_user with $op login fires AFTER the user logs in, so this would immediately log them right back out - essentially making it so they can't log in.

Comment: is there a way to do this user drupal_goto() instead of header()? If my base path changes, this code would become problematic.

Comment: drupal_goto actually uses header() in that manner. Go ahead and use it instead of header() directly.

Comment: and this code doesn't seem to work. it sets the message just fine, but people can still log in.

Comment: I'm assuming you changed "example.com" to your site?